# jQuery add element into wrap after wrapall

Tags: jquery, append, wrapall

I'm trying to wrap a hand full of elements and add an extra div into the wrap. 
I've tried -

```
$('.product-addon-one-attendee').wrapAll("<div class='single-attendee-wrapper'></div>").append( "<div class='count'>1</div>" );
```

but this is adding 'count div' into 'product addon one attende div' not the wrap 'single attendee wrapper'

If anyone know how to do this id really appreciate the help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.product-addon-one-attendee')
    .wrapAll("<div class='single-attendee-wrapper'></div>")
    .parent()
    .append( "<div class='count'>1</div>" );
```

The wrapper is now the parent of your elements, so you can use `parent` to get it.